# How to verify the ownership of a website?

Tags: validation, web, verify, ownership

I want to create a tag to allow user to claim the ownership of his website.

How would I get the tag and the match it against the one I have generated.

The tag format will be `<!--tag-->`

how will I verify this tag if I am able to get the html using `file_Get_contents("url");`

Comment: Ownership? Do you mean the domain name? What programming language are you going to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's just a string match.

```
<?php
$tagCode = "<!-- abc123 -->";
$pageContent = file_get_contents("http://www.somesite.com/");

if (strpos($pageContent, $tagCode) !== false) {
    echo "it matched!";
}
```